# ALGEBRAIC TOPOLOGY-basic books

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

My professor said me that algebraic topology is an interesting subject.So I decided to study.Sir gave me a book of FRED H Croom.But when I read it I feel it's more difficult to understand. Please help me to give a basic text to understand this topic from it's base.

Comment: I used Armstrong's "Basic Topology" in my first course, but other popular references include Munkres' "Topology" and Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" (though Hatcher is typically seen at the introductory graduate level).  There are a lot of good other introductory texts.  Unfortunately, at the more advanced level, the texts are quite lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greenburg and Harper is good.  One of them was at Santa Cruz.  There's Munkres.  Spanier is really good.  He was a fine mathematician.

I seem to remember a book by Fomenko and somebody else that had lots of illustrations, or art work with it.  But I can't find it right now.